# How to deserialize an uploaded font from a Base64String?

Tags: c#, html, filereader

I need to get the font family name from an uploaded font.  The user uploads a .ttf file.  When I try to deserialize the data I get the following error "The input stream is not a valid binary format."  The font data is uploaded via a HTML5 FileReader using readAsDataURL().

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  I suspect I'm using the wrong deserializer... but I'm not sure.

```
//clean the font data of encoding
var cleanFontData = brandingsFontAddViewModel.FontData.Split(',')[1];
var fontBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cleanFontData);

using (Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(fontBytes, 0,  fontBytes.Length))
{
    var deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
    var font = (Font)deserializer.Deserialize(memStream);
}
```

Comment: Is the file uploaded actually a font object that has been serlialised in .NET or is it just a normal file uploaded? If the latter then you'll need to find some way to read that file format. If the former then you should also show us how it gets serialised.

Comment: @Chris  It's a normal .ttf file.

Comment: Binary (de)Serialization of Font type won't produce a ttf...

Comment: Then a deserialize won't work to read it. Deserializing is for when you have a .NET object that has been serialised. What you have is just a file so you will need to find something to parse that file. There may be something built in already, I have no idea. I'm sure google will tell you something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

```
// used to store our font and make it available in our app
                var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();

                IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int) ms.Length);

                Marshal.Copy(fontBytes, 0, data, (int)ms.Length);

                pfc.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)ms.Length);

                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);

                var fontWithMime = "data:application/x-font-truetype;charset=utf-8;base64," + cleanFontData;

                fontName = pfc.Families[0].Name;
```